# Masters Data Caching Using Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to Cache all my frequently used and rarely updated data using static variables, so that it reduces database querying to a great extent. Following is my code.

```
public class Cache
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext _context;

    private static IEnumerable<ActivityGroupDto> _ActivityGroups;

    public static IEnumerable<ActivityGroupDto> ActivityGroups(bool ForceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (ForceRefresh || _ActivityGroups == null)
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            _ActivityGroups = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ActivityGroup>, IEnumerable<ActivityGroupDto>>(_context.ActivityGroups.ToList());
        }

        return _ActivityGroups;
    }
}
```

I have many such lists in my project and I don't want to repeat that method for all my lists (Applying DRY principle). Thought of using Generics and got struck, not really getting an idea how to convert that above method to generic. Following is my code.

```
public class Master<T,T1,T2,T3>
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public static IEnumerable<T> Process(T Data, bool ForceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (ForceRefresh || Data == null)
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            Data = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>>(_context.Set<T3>());
        }

        return Data;
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Added ways to make your class generic, however in dot net there are already classes in framework that target making caching, do check them out before trying to role on your own, and also try to give expressive names to type, makes the code easier to follow when you come back to it after few days

Comment: The reason why I avoid framework caching is that there is no compile time checking, frequent casting operations problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting mixed up with your types, in you scenario you should be requiring about 2 type, converting Data to DTO, `ActivityGroup => ActivityGroupDto`

I have outlined a similar class, it uses `List` not `IEnumerable`, but should help you in the right direction.

```
public class MasterCache<T, TDto>
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext _context;

    private static List<TDto> _dtoGroups;

    public static List<TDto> Process(T data, bool ForceRefresh = false)
    {
        if (ForceRefresh || _dtoGroups == null)
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
            _dtoGroups = Mapper<T, TDto>.Map(data);
        }

        return _dtoGroups;
    }
}
```

To truly benefit, your mapper would also need to be generic, here's a simple skeleton:

```
public class Mapper<T, TDto>
{
    public static List<TDto> Map(T groups)
    {
        return new List<TDto>();
    }
}
```

On top you can create the application context to be generic.

Please do keep in mind the way `static` variable behave in the generic class (i.e., they are created once per copy of a closed generic instance).

> Updated based on comments.

To store different entities and retrieve them we can use a dictionary with type as key and the object as value.

```
Dictionary<Type, object> test = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
test.Add(typeof(ActivityGroup), new object());
var result = test[typeof(ActivityGroup)];
```

This will involve casting the value into the right type, a workaround would be for all the static list to implement a standard wrapper interface (this depends on your design and what the list are used for), and use this to store the values. Since I believe you are starting out with the system and I do not have knowledge of how big it is, I do not think conversion performance should be the issue right now. For validation you can always check after conversion that the object is of required type or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, If ForceRefresh is "true " or _dtoGroups is "null", our context should pickup from database. I think that particular step is missing in the given code.

Comment: Ok, was just warning about the static variables in generics as you might end up creating multiple DbContext variables. Have not worked with entity framework so not sure what the exact impact of that will be.

Comment: Here the major challenge is to find the right entity to retrieve from dbcontext. Not sure how to do that.